# CSS rounded corners around image

Tags: html, css, images

I have tried several ways to get rounded corners around images without success. The best I got was using the image as background and applying the round corners style to the div as in [this picture](http://phowin.com/photography/SFO%20-%20Tracks%20detail%20of%20Vintage%20East-West%20Streetcar/).

Problem is that image is not linked through an img tag, so GoogleBot does not index it.

Is there a better solution just using img tag and **css** to get **images with rounded corners**?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which browsers are you testing? Most modern browsers should handle this OK directly on an `img` element. An exception could be Opera (I tested 11.5 sometime ago). And IE8 is a problem anyway. I answered a very similar question to this on StackOverflow a while back... http://stackoverflow.com/a/7284337/369434

Comment: Update... Just tested the latest version of Opera (12.02) and the rounded corners on the `img` element appear to work OK.

Comment: This belongs in http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Closed as off-topic. I'm not going to migrate it, because images with rounded corners have already been discussed [multiple times there](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+image+rounded+corners).